# Tests with `expect_doppelganger()` fail after upgrade to R 4.2.0

Tags: r, testthat

After the update to R 4.2.0, all tests using `expect_doppelganger()` from `vdiffr` fail with the following message:

```
Error in svglite_(filename, bg, width, height, pointsize, standalone,  : 
  Graphics API version mismatch
```

How can I fix these tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply reinstalling the package `vdiffr` resolved the issue. There was not even a change to the snapshot images used in the test.

More information regarding this update to the graphics engine can be found in [this blog post](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2021/12/14/updating-graphics-devices-for-r-4.2.0/index.html), where it is stated that

> For users of R packages that provide graphics devices, those packages will need to be reinstalled when updating to R 4.2.0.